# How to execute .cmd fille in Qt5

Tags: qt, cmd, qt5, shellexecute

How to execute .cmd file with this commands:

```
TASKKILL /F /PID 14364
MOVE /Y "C:/Users/BBCCA/AppData/Roaming/DWAKU2\DWAKU2.exe" "D:/DWAKU2/build-    DWAKU2-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit_Static-Release/release"
START "" "D:/DWAKU2/build-DWAKU2-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit_Static-Release/release/DWAKU2.exe"
```

How can I execute this script with command console in qt?
As you can see - first command close qt application.

---

Firstly, I tried to use QProcess to execute all commands inside it.

```
auto programmName = QFileInfo(QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()).fileName();
QProcess consola;
QString command = "cmd";
QStringList commandArgs;
QString subcommand1, subcommand2;
subcommand1 += "TASKKILL /IM ";
subcommand1 += programmName;
subcommand2 += "DEL /Q ";
subcommand2 += QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath();
commandArgs << "/c" << subcommand1 << "&&" << subcommand2;
qDebug() << commandArgs;
consola.startDetached(command, commandArgs);
consola.waitForFinished();
```

But it doesn't execute with error:

> Ошибка: Неправильный параметр или аргумент - '/Q'. Введите "TASKKILL
> /?" для получения справки по использованию.

Translation:

> Error: Incorrect parameter or argument - '/Q'. Enter "TASKKILL /?" for
> help on how to use it.

After lots of reading docs and asking ru.stuckoverflow - gave up on this idea and tried to use cmd file.
You can read it above.

Execution of this file was:

```
// Make updater script
    if (fileCorrect){
        ui->LoadingAnimationLabel->setText(bLText + "Making updater script... " + aLText);
        QFile file(appDataPath + QDir::separator() + "updater.cmd");
        if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {

            auto pid = "TASKKILL /F /PID " + QString::number(QCoreApplication::applicationPid()) + "\r\n";
            auto move = "MOVE /Y \"" + appDataPath + QDir::separator() + QFileInfo(QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()).fileName() + "\" \"" + QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "\"\r\n";
            auto start = "START \"\" \"" + QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath() + "\"\r\n";

        file.write(pid.toLocal8Bit());
        file.write(move.toLocal8Bit());
        file.write(start.toLocal8Bit());

        } else fileCorrect = false;
        file.close();
    }

    // Installing updates
    if (fileCorrect){
        ui->LoadingAnimationLabel->setText(bLText + "Installing update files... " + aLText);
        auto command = appDataPath + QDir::separator() + "updater.cmd";
        QProcess updater;
        updater.startDetached(appDataPath + QDir::separator() + "updater.cmd");
    }
```

When programm executed this file - only first command was executed.
But when I tried to execute this file by clicking it - it worked fine....

Comment: It still looks to me as if your added code is writing a batch file as UTF-8, and then trying to run that batch file, so even after the advice you've received, you still appear to be ignoring the majority of it. Could you please, based upon your newly added code, also edit your batch file content to match what it now contains when created through that new code. If you do not do that, you'll further confuse our readership.

Comment: @Compo, as I read - I make CP866, not UTF-8

Comment: Please do not respond in a way which suggests that my previous comment was incorrect. You had `pid.toUtf8()`, and have only since changed it to `pid.toLocal8Bit()`. Regardless of that, it is also clear that there is some strange whitespace in line two of your now updated batch file, which means that you will be unable to run the newly moved file. So when you told us that it works fine when clicked, that was incorrect! Also, I've already told you that Windows uses ```\``` separators, not `/`.

Comment: @Compo Sorry, i don't mean so. I don't think in a way which suggests that your previous comment was incorrect. WhiteSpaces are only in site - in file there no whitespaces. Maybe it because site have UTF-8 code and update.cmd has CP866. Win10 uses all separators, not only \ (i don't write them - I use QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath() and QDir::separator())

Comment: @Compo i tried to edit file before execution looking for comments, but have same result

Comment: @Compo as I read in docs from Mofi - there is a problem with security, because cmd.exe has parent (running Qt application) and when parent closed - children will close to

Comment: Windows **sometimes**, auto corrects incorrect separators, but that is not an excuse for doing them wrong. A robust programming code does not make assumptions that errors will be fixed by the system, it does things correctly from the outset. Also when you paste your code into your question, it doesn't randomly include multiple whitespaces in the middle of a string without any, those could only have been introduced by you. If you're closing a parent process, I would expect that its default behavior would be to also close its children too.

Comment: @Compo I tried to clear CreateProcess - it works fine!!! Thanks for helping. I will make some tests and write an answer. Maybe find how to make QProcess works. Thanks for comments - I will learn them. Thank you and Mofi very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `QProcess`, and particularly the `startDetached` method. According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached), "If the calling process exits, the detached process will continue to run unaffected."

```
    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess();
    myProcess->setProgram("updater.cmd");
    myProcess->startDetached();
```

Comment: Sorry: If you use QProcess to execute cmd file - you will execute only first command. Yes, if you use startDetached. I don't know why, but I tested it.

Comment: Ok. The docs also mention Windows users will sometimes need to run `cmd.exe` as the process, and pass the actual command as an argument to that.

Comment: Sorry. As I inspected - Qt Creator close all detached processes after closing main application in Windows. Your method wors fine